# How to continuously take backup of log files?

Tags: shell, shell-script, rhel

I have some applications in Linux which create log files of around 41 MB each. The application switches from `log.1` to `log.2` and starts overwriting `log.2` once this 41MB is completed in `log.1` file.

I want to take the backup of these files in the way that whenever the new file `log.2` reaches the size more than 1MB it take backup (gzip and store at another location) of other file (`log.1`).

I have been using a script which takes the backup of a file whenever it reaches 41MB but the trouble here is sometimes this 41MB file backup is processed by the script while the data is still getting written to the same file at a huge rate.  Because of that some seconds of log data are lost which is the reason I am trying the alternate way of making backup of other file once the new file reaches 1MB or something, so that I am sure that the other file is finished writing.

Any idea how do I do that?

Comment: Have you considered using `rsyslog` to log over the network to a remote machine? You can than take backups/snapshots over there and control the rotation of the files without disturbing this machine.

Comment: May i know more about rsyslog?

Comment: I second the comment about rsyslog. There's more information about it at http://www.rsyslog.com/

Comment: I think that's not something which can solve my problem.

Comment: Configure the chatterbox to shut up? Nobody will really read all those logs, do they.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done through logrotate , see below example for apache logs

Step 1#  First make sure logrotate is installed in your system, by default is available on almost all distro of Linux

Step 2# Create `/etc/logrotate_apache.conf` as below

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    minsize 1M
    create
    compress
    rotate 1
    lastaction
        /sbin/service httpd reload > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
        Log_dir="/var/log/httpd/Apache_$(date +%F)/"
        # move to other location
        [[ ! -d "${Log_dir}" ]] && /bin/mkdir "${Log_dir}" &&  /bin/mv /var/log/httpd/*.gz "${Log_dir}"
    endscript
}

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Step 3# Set Cron task as below

```
00 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate_apache.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try **logrotate**, Some Examples are mentioned [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/)

The **size** option will let you rotate the log once it reaches a specified size, say 41MB.
Use the **postrotate** option, to execute a custom script which you can use to transfer the rotated log file to another location.